# Find out how much memory is used by the script

Tags: javascript, node.js

in PHP I can use `memory_get_usage()`.

Is there anything like that in nodejs? The memwatch library doesn't seem to provide that info, it only emits some events when a "leak" occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get concerned object describing the memory usage of the Node process.

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
```

result:

```
{ rss: 4935680,
  vsize: 41893888,
  heapTotal: 1826816,
  heapUsed: 650472 }
```

heapTotal and heapUsed refer to V8's memory usage.

Here is link: [Original Link](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/all.html#process.memoryUsage)

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this article https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/ ? There are some nice examples.

What about memwatch's stats event ?

```
var memwatch = require('memwatch');
memwatch.on('stats', function(stats) {
// do something with post-gc memory usage stats
});
```